# Can a distributed priority blocking queue be used (somehow) for hazelcast distributed executor services?

Tags: hazelcast

I can create a "standalone, normal" (ie not using Hazelcast; not distributed) executor service using a *priority blocking queue* by following the simple example from https://jvmaware.com/priority-queue-and-threadpool/

However, I tried to adapt the same strategy to support *PRIORITIZATION* of submitted tasks for Hazelcast, but couldn't get it to work. Is there a way I can pass a Hazelcast distributed priority queue to the Hazelcast executor service to use? (I tried to do  `ConcurrencyUtil.setDefaultAsyncExecutor(tpe);` where `tpe` is the custom thread pool executor as described in the first link, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the underlying queue implementation for IExecutorService **from configuration**.

If you look at the source code that creates ExecutorService
implementation

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spi/impl/executionservice/impl/ExecutionServiceImpl.java#L198

You can see that **NamedThreadPoolExecutor**  is created with a hard coded **LinkedBlockingQueue**

And the **CachedExecutorServiceDelegate** also has hard coded **LinkedBlockingQueue**
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/internal/util/executor/CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java#L68